# Linking MKL to MPI

Tags: mpi, intel-mkl

I want to use MKL with MPI in a program I'm writing so I have created a bash file using mpic++ as my compiler.
For that reason I cannot use flags like -mkl because they produce errors. If I don't use the flags I get dozens of

```
undefined reference to 'PARDISO'
undefined reference to 'MKL_Set_Num_Threads'
undefined reference to 'cblas_dnrm2'
```

and so on... What can I do to solve this since it produces an exit status 1?

I have Ubuntu 15.10 and when I installed MKL in the optional prerequisites there was

```
-- Intel(R) MPI Library, Development Kit 5.0 Update 1 for Linux* OS: Unsupported OS
```

and when I checked the libraries in

```
 /opt/intel
```

there wasn't an impi library. Could this be the problem? (there was however an mpirt library).

Comment: What are your actual linker lines? What is the MPI implementation you use? Which versions? Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14562506/620382)?

Answer (score 0):

`-mkl` is for Intel compiler only. It simplifies the link line options you need to pass to the compiler.  If you use other compilers, you need to specify those options explicitly. [Intel® Math Kernel Library Link Line Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) is the tool to help you generate the correct options.